# Angular routes with params and getting params

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

A user will be clicking a link in an email like this:

```
do-something/doSomething?thing=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

How can I define the route in the router and subscribe to get params?

Currently in router I have:

```js
    {
     path: 'do-something/:id',
     component: DoSomethingComponent
    },
```

In the component:

```js
    ngOnInit() {
     this.sub = this.route
      .params
      .subscribe(params => {
       console.log(params)
      });
    }
```

However, the route never matches. Shouldn't ":id" consider anything after reset-password as a param?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this one i got for angular site

```
import { Component, OnInit }  from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute }     from '@angular/router';
import { Observable }         from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  template:  `
    <p>Dashboard</p>
    <p>Session ID: {{ sessionId | async }}</p>
  `
})
export class AdminDashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
   //read query param
    this.route
      .queryParamMap
      .map(params => console.log(params.get('thing')););

     //read param value 
      this.route
      .paramMap
      .map((params: ParamMap) => 
                           console.log(params.get('id')));
  }
}
```

Read Routinh here : https://angular.io/guide/router#!#optional-route-parameters

---

try like this

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'do-something/:id', component: DoSomethingComponent, name: 'Details'}];
```

now navigation like

```
this.router.navigate( [
  'Details', { id: 'idvalue', param1: 'value1'
}]);//this you can try from code
```

this match

```
do-something/idvalue?param1=value1. //this try from browser
```

read query param like this

```
ngOnInit() {
  // Capture the access token and code
  this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
          let thing = params['thing'];
      });
}
```

or try this

```
(new URL(location)).searchParams.get("parameter_name")
```

Comment: what route have you defined in the router?

Comment: @Anthony - define route in route.ts file

Comment: When I subscribe to route and  console.log(params) I only get {id: "idvalue"} not the other param values

Comment: @Anthony- thanks to you i am also trying at my end becuase i never tried this in my example ...

Answer (score 1):

More than 1 hour wasted.

Both below did not work:
  `this.route.paramMap` &
  `this.route.params`

Only below worked:
`this.route.queryParams`

1.URL is like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/employee?tab=admin
```

2.Need to extract the value of query parameter `tab`, which is `admin`

3.Code that worked is:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    console.error(" ==== ", params["tab"]); // this will print `admin`
    // this.tabNameFromUrl = params["tab"];
  });
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `http://localhost:4200/employee?id=13` => `queryParams` -----------------
`http://localhost:4200/employee/13` => `params`

Comment: The question did start with query params URL. Thanks for the additional details, your details will help someone soon.